# elasticsearch index_name with multi_field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 separate indexes, each containing a different type
I want to get combined records from both.

The problem is that one type has field '**email**', the other has '**work_email**'. However I want to treat them as the same thing for sorting purposes.
That is why I try to use **index_name** in one of the types.

Here are mappings:

**Index1:**

```
  "mappings": {
     "people": {
        "properties": {
           "work_email": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_name": "email",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

**Index2:**

```
  "mappings": {
     "companies": {
        "properties": {
           "email": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

I expect this to work:

```
GET /index1,index2/people,companies/_search?
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "email.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But, I get an error that there is no such field in the 'people' type.
Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Here you can find a recreation script that illustrates the problem: https://gist.github.com/pmishev/11375297

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Found this question researching the same problem. In my case I'm also specifying index_name, but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a 'copy_to' property in my mapping:

```
 "mappings": {
 "people": {
    "properties": {
       "work_email": {
          "type": "string",
          "copy_to": "email",
          "fields": {
             "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

}

So now I can address both fields as **email**.
It's not ideal, as this means that the email field is actually indexed twice, but that was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in the way you map the multi field..Check out the below mapping and try to index..You should get the results

```
"mappings": {
 "people": {
    "properties": {
           "work_email":{
            "type": "multi_field", 
            "fields": {
                "work_email":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_name": "email"
                },
                "raw":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

We should specify the type to multi_field and under the fields we should specify the required fields....

Comment: Thank you for replying, but the result is the same. Your mapping is just the old format, which was removed in version 1.0
[link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)